# Custom page templates with WooThemes Function theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, templates

Fairly new to WordPress.org. I've built a couple of sites using WordPress.com, and have pretty solid HTML and CSS knowledge. I don't know PHP from a bar of soap.

I'm building a new site using a WooThemes theme, Function. I've got my wireframes done, and came to the conclusion that I should create some custom page templates. Upon further reading I've discovered that it potentially requires PHP knowledge. So I am pretty clear on what the process involves in creating custom templates.

The custom page templates I have in mind are nothing dramatically different from what is already provided. I intended on duplicating an existing template and just customising the main body layout by introducing some divs and other HTML elements so that similar pages can consistently be created quite easily.

Having no experience at this level of WordPress customisation, I wanted to ask your opinion:

Should I attempt to make these custom page templates, given my lack of PHP, or should I just create my first page of each type, then duplicate it and modify the content?

Thanks for your help,
Jon

Comment: I would personally consider doing it both ways and weigh the odds.  If you are clear on not learning PHP then it may be easier to not use a multi-template layout.  But do consider learning PHP or at least the context that is used for wordpress so that you can have more versatility with your design.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have no doubt I'll pick up what's needed of PHP as I go along... and you're right - it's better to know how to do it. Thanks for making it clear that there is no obviously wrong path to choose!